# Sql Query to show the second row data into first row and third row data into second row and so on using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table in my sql server.That table has one column.

Example table name : Sample

Column Name : data

data

```
-----------
7/11/2014 12:00:00 AM

7/31/2014 12:00:00 AM

8/21/2014 12:00:00 AM

9/19/2014 12:00:00 AM

11/20/2014 12:00:00 AM

12/18/2014 12:00:00 AM

1/22/2015 12:00:00 AM
```

So by this data I want to add an extra column and in that column I want the second row data into first row, third row data into second row ...so on.

Example:

```
data                        New Column                                                                         

-----------                  ----------------------                                                                                      

7/11/2014 12:00:00 AM        7/31/2014 12:00:00 AM                                                                                               

7/31/2014 12:00:00 AM        8/21/2014 12:00:00 AM                                                                                              

8/21/2014 12:00:00 AM        9/19/2014 12:00:00 AM                                                                                              

9/19/2014 12:00:00 AM        11/20/2014 12:00:00 AM                                                                                                                                                                              

11/20/2014 12:00:00 AM       12/18/2014 12:00:00 AM                                                                                                                         

12/18/2014 12:00:00 AM       1/22/2015 12:00:00 AM                                                                                              

1/22/2015 12:00:00 AM        Null
```

Provide me the suggestions how I will get my expected output.

Comment: Is there any primary key into the table ?

Comment: Is there a reason not to do this in a scripting language like php or python once you have retreived the data?

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (DateColumn DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
('7/11/2014 12:00:00 AM'),
('7/31/2014 12:00:00 AM'),
('8/21/2014 12:00:00 AM'),
('9/19/2014 12:00:00 AM'),
('11/20/2014 12:00:00 AM'),
('12/18/2014 12:00:00 AM'),
('1/22/2015 12:00:00 AM')
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT DateColumn
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateColumn) rn  
 FROM @Table
 )
SELECT A.DateColumn AS DateColumn1
      ,B.DateColumn AS DateColumn2
FROM CTE A 
LEFT JOIN CTE B ON A.rn = B.rn - 1
```

**Result**

```
╔═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║       DateColumn1       ║       DateColumn2       ║
╠═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 2014-07-11 00:00:00.000 ║ 2014-07-31 00:00:00.000 ║
║ 2014-07-31 00:00:00.000 ║ 2014-08-21 00:00:00.000 ║
║ 2014-08-21 00:00:00.000 ║ 2014-09-19 00:00:00.000 ║
║ 2014-09-19 00:00:00.000 ║ 2014-11-20 00:00:00.000 ║
║ 2014-11-20 00:00:00.000 ║ 2014-12-18 00:00:00.000 ║
║ 2014-12-18 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-01-22 00:00:00.000 ║
║ 2015-01-22 00:00:00.000 ║ NULL                    ║
╚═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: can you suggest me in the below problem i am getting output but null value in 1st row

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (DateColumn DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
('7/11/2014 12:00:00 AM'),
('7/31/2014 12:00:00 AM'),
('8/21/2014 12:00:00 AM'),
('9/19/2014 12:00:00 AM'),
('11/20/2014 12:00:00 AM'),
('12/18/2014 12:00:00 AM'),
('1/22/2015 12:00:00 AM')

;WITH CTE AS (
select DateColumn,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY DATECOLUMN)RN from @Table
)
select  DATECOLUMN,  DATECOLUMN  As NewColumn from CTE WHERE RN  > 1
UNION ALL 
select  DATECOLUMN,CASE WHEN RN = 1 then NULL ELSE ' ' END  As NewColumn 
from CTE  WHERE RN  = 1 
ORDER BY DATECOLUMN
```